# Mysql subquery with between

Tags: mysql, cakephp, subquery, acl, between

I'm working with ACL in CakePHP, and would like to fetch all entries that are allowed for the current user.

Simplified, I have two tables:

Interval:

```
**lft**| **rght**
10   |  20
40   |  60
90   |  92
```

Acos:

```
**foreign_key** | **lft** | **rght**
3               |    15   |  17
4               |    25   |  27
5               |    45   |  47
6               |    49   |  51
7               |    81   |  83
```

Now I would like to fetch the foreign_keys FROM Acos which have lft and rght values between the lft and rght from Interval

In the above example we get foreign_key 3, 5, 6.

On a side note. The "Interval" table does not actually exist. The values came from this query (also the acos table):

```
 SELECT lft, rght FROM acos WHERE id IN ( 
        SELECT aco_id FROM  aros_acos  WHERE 
        aro_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM aros WHERE foreign_key = 48 && model =  'User' )
        OR 
        aro_id = (SELECT id FROM aros WHERE foreign_key = 48 && model =  'User' )
 )
```

I don't hope the example above is too messy. Please comment if there are any uncertainties.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct foreign_key
from Acos
join
    (
        SELECT lft, rght
        FROM acos
        WHERE
            id IN ( 
                SELECT aco_id
                FROM
                    aros_acos a,
                    (
                        select parent_id, id
                        from aros
                        where foreign_key = 48 && model =  'User'
                    ) x
                WHERE
                    a.aro_id = x.id
                    OR a.aro_id = x.parent_id
            )
    ) Interval
on
    Acos.lft>=Interval.lft
    and acos.rght<=Interval.rght
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you see any way to optimize the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables like this:

```
SELECT foreign_key from Acos a INNER JOIN Interval i ON
  (i.lft <= a.lft AND i.rght>=a.rght)
```

The join condition `(i.lft <= a.lft AND i.rght>=a.rght)`ensures that range in Acos is within or equal to the range of Interval, without going over.

If there are multiple matching intervals, you'll get multiple rows in the result. Use a GROUP BY or DISTINCT to get just the foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't make you example work at first, so I accepted arturr's answer -  although your answers were very similar. 
I made it work by adding "distinct":

SELECT distinct foreign_key from Acos a INNER JOIN Interval i ON
  (i.lft <= a.lft AND i.rght>=a.rght)

Comment: Glad you got it working - I guess you didn't see my last paragraph, where I mention about using Distinct? :D